# iOS 8 Pdf output-minimum font scaling to fit frame

Tags: ios, pdf, text, fonts, measure

I'm using the code below to write text to a pdf. This is pretty standard stuff, using attributes to style the text.

Use of attributes works but I need to be able to shrink the text to fit the available frame, similar to a UILabel. There doesn't appear to be any kind of minimum font size setting, which probably makes sense as attributed text can be variable in font and sizes.

So, is there a way to **measure the proposed size of the text** when outputting to **pdf** to see if it will fit the frame, consequently allowing me to reduce my font size attributes manually?

```
-(void)drawText:(NSString*)text inFrame:(CGRect)frameRect withAttributes:(NSDictionary*)attributes
{
    CFStringRef stringRef = (__bridge CFStringRef)text;

    CFDictionaryRef attributeRef = (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)attributes;

    CFAttributedStringRef currentText = CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, stringRef, attributeRef);
    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(currentText);

    CGMutablePathRef framePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddRect(framePath, NULL, frameRect);

    CFRange currentRange = CFRangeMake(0, 0);
    CTFrameRef frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, currentRange, framePath, NULL);
    CGPathRelease(framePath);

    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(currentContext, CGAffineTransformIdentity);

    CGFloat offset = (frameRect.origin.y*2)+frameRect.size.height;
    CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, offset);
    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);

    CTFrameDraw(frameRef, currentContext);

    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, -offset);

    CFRelease(frameRef);
    CFRelease(framesetter);
    CFRelease(currentText);
}
```

Comment: pdf dot size is 1/72 inch, it should be possible to calculate the fontsize to print from there.

Comment: Can you expand on that? There's a lot of factors that determine the text's rectangle?